# iOS UINavigationController loading to white screen but app is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm developing an app with a single ViewController. When I run the app, it goes to that default LaunchScreen that is included when you start the file, and then proceeds to the ViewController. Everything is fine, it loads and does everything it's supposed to, which includes some audio feedback.

From my storyboard then, I've clicked on the existing ViewController and then Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. Navigation Controller appears, the Storyboard reflects the Navigation Bar on both screens, and the Navigation Controller has "Is Initial View Controller" checked. Great.

Now, however, if I run the app, the LaunchScreen goes and then a blank white screen follows. No navigation bar, none of the original interface. However, I still get my audio feedback - the app is running just fine.

So what's going on?

Let me know if there's anything you'd like to see (code, screenshots, etc.).

Comment: The first thing to do is figure out what the heck you're seeing. In `didFinishingLaunching`, color the window background red. If the app now launches to red, we now know you're seeing the window itself.

Comment: check ViewController class in storyboard & follow @matt comment.

Comment: Alright, in AppDelegate.m I've adjusted the `didFinishLaunching` function to the following: 

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self.window setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    return YES;
}`


But I don't see any tint happening, still a white screen.

Comment: Not the tint color, dude. The tint is what color button text will be! Color the window color (its `backgroundColor`).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I should have prefaced with "I'm pretty new to iOS development". Rather then I've got `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` and still do not see that reflected.

Comment: Okay, so now do the same thing for your view controller's view in the storyboard. Give it a red background color in the storyboard. Now launch. Do you see red?

Comment: At the end of ViewController.m's `viewDidLoad` function: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`, but I don't see red.

Comment: Okay, good. But you are not very good at following directions, are you? Please also try what I actually said: color the view red _in the storyboard_. Why does that make a difference? Because I don't necessarily believe that the view you are seeing belongs to this view controller.

Comment: Also FYI you don't seem to understand how to use stack overflow: when you reply to me in a comment say `@matt` or I won't see the comment. Don't make me keep checking back here. Thanks.

Comment: @matt Sorry about that, and thanks for your patience. I colored the view red from the storyboard, but still don't see red when I run the app. So this would mean I'm seeing a different ViewController than what's on my Storyboard, but whatever view is being run is still inheriting my ViewController class?

Comment: I don't know what it means, except that we have not yet identified the view you are seeing. We have no idea where it comes from. It is not the window. It is not your view controller's view in code. It is not your view controller's view in the storyboard. What else have you got? Is there _another_ view controller in the storyboard? I'm suggesting you should try coloring every view of every scene, until you learn what the heck this white thing is.

Comment: Xcode > Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy

Comment: @matt There isn't another View Controller on the story board. I'll keep poking around with coloring as a debug tool.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I have no idea how to interpret the result of that. Tips?

Comment: It may help you to figure out which view is being displayed. Do you have a bit of code sample? Or post your project somewhere for inspection (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using PixateFreestyle to style some elements. At some point it seems I had rather heavy-handidly added:

```
view {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Which covered the views nested in the root view controller. Figured it out when I noticed copying my classes to another project resulted in the same issues and started commenting out chunks. Took out the Pixate initialization and regained my view.

Thanks to everyone who offered help. If nothing else, I learned more about debugging iOS apps.

Comment: And actually the last thing you did - try to reproduce the issue in another, simpler project - is itself a _very_ important way of debugging! I wish more people would do that.